# Dynamically allocating an array of structs trouble

Tags: c++

The structure I am using is:

```
struct Employee {
    char firstName[10];
    char lastName[10];
    char SSN[11];
    double wage;
    int hours;
    char workerStatus;
};
```

When trying to create an array, I can do

```
Employee workers[11];
```

And it'll create an array consisting of 11 employees

However, when I try

```
Employee* workers = new Employee[11];
```

It'll only give me one variable called workers.
Why is this happening

Comment: You get exactly one variable called `workers` in both cases, and both can be used as an array (with 2 different meanings of "array" indeed) of 11 `Employee`s. What exactly is your question?

Comment: What did you expect would happen?

Comment: [This is what visual studio shows when I do Employee workers[11](https://gyazo.com/93090967909b04e24791ee3b46d7f4c2). One the other hand when trying to dynamically allocate it, [this](https://gyazo.com/26b77a2e547c782d65c7f4681fefb7a8) is what it gives.

Comment: @000: That's a fact of your debugger, and is due to the fundamental nature of what an array is, vs what a pointer-to-one-or-more-objects is. You must remember that a debugger is a _view_ on your program according only to the names of variables that are in scope, and shouldn't be taken so literally!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this happening

Because that's literally what you asked your computer to make happen.

**In fact, in *both* cases, you have one variable named `workers`.**

```
Employee* workers = new Employee[11];
```

Here you asked it to create one variable `workers`, a pointer of type `Employee*`, and make it point to a dynamically-allocated block of 11 `Employee` objects.

```
Employee workers[11];
```

And here you asked it to create a variable `workers`, an array of type `Employee[11]`.

In both cases, the underlying data consists of 11 `Employee`s, but in the case of the pointer, the number of `Employee`s is not baked into the type. That's why your debugger cannot automatically show you all the `Employee`s at once: it doesn't know how many there are! It can only show you the `Employee` that is *currently* being pointed to by `worker`. But you could safely increment `worker` ten times to see the other `Employee`s.

I don't know why you expected two completely different lines of code to do the same thing.

Comment: The first `workers` only points to *one* `Employee`, but it's the first in a sequence of 11.

Comment: @KerrekSB: See, here's where things get a little woolly. Because according to the type system it (always (while valid)) points to _one_ `Employee`, but according to the code it (currently) points to a block of 11 `Employees`, which is what I went for above ... and according to the memory allocator the same is true, which is how `delete[] workers` works. So really there are a few ways to look at it. I reckon the above is clear enough for now.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up. Pointers are still new to me. Now that I know to increment the pointer, everything is working out.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think it's pretty clear: The array-new expression returns a pointer *to the first element* of the dynamic array. The array is there, but there's no expression whose value is the array, and you have to use pointer arithmetic to get at all the array elements.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think you missed the point of what I was saying but never mind